# Cant delete/update for newly items in ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have problem deleting new items in crud, for old data it works but for newly added item its not. Here's my code

form

```
@foreach ($campaigns as $campaign)
    <tr id="campaign{{ $campaign->campaign_id }}">
        <td id="campaign_no">{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td id="td-campaign-{{ $campaign->campaign_id }}">{{ $campaign->campaign_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $campaign->created_at }}</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">{{ $campaign->status }}</span></td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-icon btn-warning btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs"><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="icon-rocket"></i></span></button> 
            <button class="btn btn-icon btn-secondary btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs open-modal" value="{{ $campaign->campaign_id }}" ><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span></button>  
            <button class="btn btn-icon btn-danger btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs delete-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal" value="{{ $campaign->campaign_id }}"><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></button> 
        </td>
   </tr>                           
@endforeach
```

modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="purchaseModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="purchaseLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="purchaseLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            Are you sure?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-link" id="delete-now" value="">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js add item:

```
$("#btn-save").click(function (e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = {
        campaign_name: jQuery('#campaign_name').val(),
    };
    var state = jQuery('#btn-save').val();
    var type = "POST";
    var link_id = jQuery('#link_id').val();
    var ajaxurl = 'campaign/save';
    if (state == "Update") {
        type = "POST";
        ajaxurl = 'campaign/update/'+link_id;
       //alert('update detected');
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

               if (state == "add") {


            var link = '<tr id="link' + data.id + '">';
            link += '<td>' + $('#increment').val() + '</td><td>' + data.campaign_name + '</td><td>Few moments ago</td><td><span class="badge badge-success">' + data.status + '</span></td>';
            link += '<td><button class="btn btn-icon btn-warning btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs"><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="icon-rocket"></i></span></button> <button class="btn btn-icon btn-secondary btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs"><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span></button>  <button class="btn btn-icon btn-danger btn-icon-style-1 btn-xs delete-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#purchaseModal" value="'+data.id+'"><span class="btn-icon-wrap"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span></button> </td>';

            jQuery('#campaign-list').append(link);
            $.toast({
                text: '<i class="jq-toast-icon ti-check-box"></i><p>Added successfully!</p>',
                position: 'bottom-right',
                loaderBg:'#7a5449',
                class: 'jq-has-icon jq-toast-success',
                hideAfter: 3500, 
                stack: 6,
                showHideTransition: 'fade'
              });
            } else {
                $.get('campaign/edit/' + link_id, function (data) {

                     $('#td-campaign-'+link_id).html(data[0].campaign_name);
                     $.toast({
                        text: '<i class="jq-toast-icon ti-check-box"></i><p>Changes saved!</p>',
                        position: 'bottom-right',
                        loaderBg:'#7a5449',
                        class: 'jq-has-icon jq-toast-success',
                        hideAfter: 3500, 
                        stack: 6,
                        showHideTransition: 'fade'
                      });
                 //  $("#campaign" + link_id).replaceWith(newx);

                })




            }
            jQuery('#modalFormData').trigger("reset");
            jQuery('#linkEditorModal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('Failed');
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

js delete item:

```
jQuery('.delete-modal').click(function () {
    var link_id = $(this).val();
    alert(link_id); //the return is null, but for old item its not.
    jQuery('#delete-now').val(link_id);

});

////----- DELETE a link and remove from the page -----////
jQuery('.delete-link').click(function () {
    var link_id = $(this).val();
    alert(link_id); //the return is null, but for old item its not.
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: 'campaign/delete/' + link_id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#campaign" + link_id).remove();
            jQuery('#purchaseModal').modal('hide');
            $.toast({
                text: '<i class="jq-toast-icon ti-check-box"></i><p>Deleted successfully!</p>',
                position: 'bottom-right',
                loaderBg:'#7a5449',
                class: 'jq-has-icon jq-toast-success',
                hideAfter: 3500, 
                stack: 6,
                showHideTransition: 'fade'
              });
              location.reload();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

route:

```
Route::delete('/campaign/delete/{link_id?}', function ($link_id) {
    $campaign = Campaign::where('campaign_id',$link_id)->delete();
    return Response::json($campaign);
});
```

I have a write alert and it shows nothing for value id, what is wrong with the code?

Laravel is a free, open-source PHP web framework, created by Taylor Otwell and intended for the development of web applications following the model–view–controller architectural pattern and based on Symfony.

Comment: Selectors and event handlers specified at page load will only match elements which exist at page load. You are adding new elements *after* page load, and your event listeners will not match them - jQuery doesn't know about those new elements.  You need to delegate your handlers to an element that exists at load, and filter to match only your target elements.  This is a very common problem, and there are many duplicates and variations here on SO, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach events to dynamic HTML elements with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery)